# Android app ( in emulator ) does not connect to local rest API through http

Tags: android, api, rest, http, android-emulator

Android avd emulator to local api in docker. I can access to it through postman or any web browser.

```
@Override
public Map<?, ?> getData() {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/rest/habits/";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);

    StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String a = "1";
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                    String a = "";
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    return null;
}
}
```

The only error I got is "com.android.volley.ClientError", what the heck is wrong?

Ty in advance.

edit:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.habits_builder_android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Habits_builder_android">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Habits_builder_android.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And it is Android API 28.

And the only thing in the traceback that could useful and I did not mention is: E/Volley: [549] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:8000/rest/habits/.

I know, bad request, but it is a simple get and I've copy/pasted the headers in postman and it works.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: On an Android 10+ emulator? Google for clear text traffic.

Comment: Try the url in a browser on the emulator.

Comment: I'm pretty retarded and the issue was about I don't accept request from emulator on my docker service :)

Ty @ blackapps , I did not think to test it from web browser emulator. Feel free to put this response and I will mark your answer as the valid one.

Thank to the others too.